# Dart How to distinct (unique) `List<List<Object>>`

Tags: dart

I have a `List<List<Object>>>`. What is the best **readable** way to unique my list?

For instance:

```
[[A, B], [B, A], [B, C, B]]
```

to:

```
[[A, B], [B, C, B]]
```

Comment: I would start by thinking about the choice of data structures. If you want your outer list to contain only unique elements, you probably want to use a set instead of a list. As for your inner lists, do these contain an arbitrary amount of elements, or do these represent pairs of data? If it is a pair of data, I would at least consider modeling it as a class with descriptive names rather than a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are alright with modelling the result as a `Set<Set<Object>>`, I would suggest this approach.

I am using the [collection package](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) because it provides an easy way to check if two collections are equal.

```dart
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  List<List<String>> items = [
    ['A', 'B'],
    ['B', 'A'],
    ['B', 'C'],
  ];

  Set<Set<String>> unique = HashSet<Set<String>>(
    equals: SetEquality().equals,
    hashCode: SetEquality().hash,
  );

  unique.addAll(items.map((v) => v.toSet()));

  print(items);
  print(unique);
}
```

output

```
[[A, B], [B, A], [B, C]]
{{A, B}, {B, C}}
```

---

Since the inner lists

1. are arbitrary length
2. can contain duplicates
3. are not necessarily in the same order (but we want to treat different orderings as the same list)

It does make things more complicated, but you can use the same general approach. Here we will keep the inner elements as lists, but we will provide definitions for equals and hashCode that take the above constraints into account.

If the elements implement [Comparable](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/Comparable-class.html#:%7E:text=Comparable%20class%20Null%20safety,natural%20ordering%20of%20a%20type.) then you can use `.sorted()` to account for constraint #3, and `ListEquality().equals` and `ListEquality().hash` to account for constraints #1 and #2.

```dart
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  List<List<String>> items = [
    ['A', 'B'],
    ['B', 'A'],
    ['B', 'C', 'B'],
  ];

  Set<List<String>> unique = HashSet<List<String>>(
    equals: (a, b) => ListEquality().equals(a.sorted(), b.sorted()),
    hashCode: (a) => ListEquality().hash(a.sorted()),
  );

  unique.addAll(items);

  print(items);
  print(unique);
}
```

output

```
[[A, B], [B, A], [B, C, B]]
{[A, B], [B, C, B]}
```

---

However, what if the elements don't implement `Comparable`?

You have a few options in this case.

First, the `.sorted()` method optionally accepts a function that you can use to provide custom sorting logic.

The other approach would be to get a count of occurrences of each element in the list and compare the counts. I have implemented this approach below.

```dart
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  List<List<String>> items = [
    ['A', 'B'],
    ['B', 'A'],
    ['B', 'C', 'B'],
  ];

  Set<List<String>> unique = HashSet<List<String>>(
    equals: (a, b) => MapEquality().equals(counts(a), counts(b)),
    hashCode: (a) => MapEquality().hash(counts(a)),
  );

  unique.addAll(items);

  print(items);
  print(unique);
}

Map<T, int> counts<T>(List<T> items) {
  Map<T, int> result = {};
  for (final item in items) {
    result.update(item, (v) => v + 1, ifAbsent: () => 1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

output

```
[[A, B], [B, A], [B, C, B]]
{[B, C, B], [A, B]}
```

Note that the elements are in a different order than the previous solution, this is because `HashSet` does not preserve the insertion order, if you do want to preserve the order you can use a `LinkedHashSet` instead.

Comment: Hey @mmcdon20, thanks for your replying. My inner lists are arbitrary and not necessarily unique (updated my question example).

Comment: @genericUser see updated answer with additional solutions.